# Alternative to closing a CipherInputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, encryption, objectinputstream

I'm having trouble because I need to close de CIS (or I won't get the last 16 bytes) but I can't because I'm using it over a socket:

```
cis = new CipherInputStream(new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream));
```

(not exactly this, but it is how it's constructed).

So, if I close the socket, the program then tries to use it and I get an Exception for it...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force a CipherOutputStream to finish encrypting but leave the underlying stream open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449103/how-can-i-force-a-cipheroutputstream-to-finish-encrypting-but-leave-the-underlyi)

Comment: npe, it's not a duplicate, the problem is with sipherinputstream not outputstream

Comment: If you close the CIS you must have +already+ read the last 256 bytes, because you sure can't get them afterwards. What's the problem here?

Comment: the problem is that I can't close the CIS or it will close all my streams associated with that one (that have the same socket) and I still want to perform reds/writes on them. It also doesn't write/read the last 16 bytes of the file...

Comment: btw, I corrected the question, I meant to say 16 not 256... sorry

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to close a `CipherInputStream` to read the last block of data. That wouldn't make any sense.

What is happening is that your `CipherInputStream` has read all of the data in the final cipher text block, but is blocked in a `read()` call on the underlying stream. Detection of the end of the stream triggers the `CipherInputStream` to invoke `doFinal()` on its cipher instead of `update()`. Normally, this would happen because the end of the stream has been reached, in your case, because the socket was closed.

If you want to avoid closing the socket, you'll need to know the length of the cipher text. This might come from an HTTP header, or some other protocol that you create to transmit the encrypted data.

Extend `FilterInputStream` with a class that keeps track of how many bytes have been consumed (don't forget about the `skip()` method), and returns -1 from the `read()` method when the specified length of cipher text has been read. Override the `close()` method in your derived class so that it does not close the underlying stream.

Comment: that was very thorough, however, I do not believe I possess the skills nor the time to take such strategy into consideration, despite fully understanding it and it's certainty to work

Comment: I can't vouch for Apache Commons, but [they do claim to provide exactly this functionality.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BoundedInputStream.html)

Comment: guess I'll have to look into that